# Why is tty1 orange?

Tags: 16.04

All the text in tty1 is orange, but tty2-6 are all white. This could be part of a bigger problem that I'm creating another "ask" for right now, but for now I just want to work on understanding what's going on.

Comment: Is it also orange after you login and type `reset`?

Comment: @AndreaLazzarotto Yes, it's always orange. I've reset my computer multiple times since it started and it has been orange every time

Comment: Please note that typing `reset` has nothing to do with a system reset (or a reboot). ;)

Answer (score 2):

When Ubuntu is loading, you probably see white `.` which change to orange, then back to white.

What's happened is this animation has ended with the last `.` being orange, and for some reason the colour reset did not work.

It's no big issue - just a little bug.